# How do I add an incrementing number to multiple rows in a database table

Tags: sql, database, sql-update, sybase

I need to add line items to a table.  Here is an example of what I have (on a much smaller scale):

```
shiptoid,lineitem
642218,0
642218,0
642218,0
3041340,0
3041077,0
3041077,0
```

And this is what I need

```
shiptoid,lineitem
642218,1
642218,2
642218,3
3041340,1
3041077,1
3041077,2
```

For each unique shiptoid, I need an incrementing line item number that starts at 1.  I've done something similar in the past, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Is this SQL Server?  If so, have you looked at `row_number() over (partition by ... order by ...)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server, this will work:

```
declare @tbl table (shiptoid int)

insert into @tbl values (642218), (642218), (642218), (3041340), (3041077), (3041077)

select shiptoid, row_number() over (partition by shiptoid order by shiptoid) as lineitem    from @tbl
```

Here is what it returns:

```
shiptoid    lineitem
----------- --------------------
642218      1
642218      2
642218      3
3041077     1
3041077     2
3041340     1
```

Comment: +1 for your SQLServer Query and also for evaluating/giving great comments for everyone's answers. That's the spirit :)

Answer (score 0):

**OLD QUERIES**

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY ShiptoID) AS Row, 
    ShiptoID
FROM YourShip
```

For MYSQL:

```
SELECT s.shiptoid, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS Row
  FROM yourship s, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

For Oracle:

```
SELECT ShiptoID, ROWNUM AS Row, 
    ShiptoID
FROM YourShip
```

---

### UPDATED QUERIES

For MySQL: * [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d6a9/2) : ignore the other tables in the same page.

Query:

```
select y.shiptoID, y.row 
      from (select shiptoID,
      @row:=if(@x=shiptoID,@row,0) + 1 as row,
      @x:=shiptoID 
                from yourship
            order by shiptoID, row asc
    )as y
```

Results:

```
SHIPTOID    ROW
642218      1
642218      2
642218      3
3041077     1
3041077     2
3041340     1
```

For Oracle: Oracle has `RANK()`, `DENSE_RANK()` `OVER PARTITION` similar to MYSQL.

So we can use similar query as MYSQL in ORACLE. But the best part is, that I used `ROWNUM` in the `ORDER BY` clause ;) **So to say easiest logic/syntax out of all 3**

Reference : * [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5f9b/2)

Query:

```
SELECT shiptoID, 
DENSE_RANK() OVER 
(PARTITION BY shiptoID ORDER BY rownum) AS row
FROM yourShip
;
```

Results:

```
SHIPTOID    ROW
642218      1
642218      2
642218      3
3041077     1
3041077     2
3041340     1
```

Comment: I can't comment on **MySQL** or **Oracle**, but the **SQL Server** code doesn't restart the count for each new `ShiptoID`, like the OP requested.  You have to use `partition by` to accomplish that.  If the same is possible in **MySQL**  and **Oracle**, I'd be interested in seeing you update your answer.  +1 if you do!

Comment: @JamesL. I guess while I am yet to update the answer, I am getting downvoted here :( Should count on your +1 then :) I really did miss out the row number, my bad only saw incrementing...sigh

Comment: The Oracle query won't do what's expected as well (and besides Oracle supports standard windowing functions as well)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : just updated with another way for Oracle. :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL (which works with most modern DBMS):

```
SELECT shiptoid,
       row_number() over (partition by shiptoid) as lineitem
FROM the_table;
```

Comment: Except, if it is MSSQLServer, you must include the `order by` with the `partition by` or you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: @JamesL.: ah! Microsoft's ignorance regarding the ANSI standard again ;) Thanks for pointing that out.